# Unknown ruby interpreter string component: 'ruby_1.9.3' when switching directories

Tags: ruby, macos, jruby

When I cd into my project directory I get the following error:
Unknown ruby interpreter string component: 'ruby_1.9.3'.
The error doesn't seem to cause any problems as everything works as expected but I'm wondering what would cause the terminal to display the error when switching into a directory.

Environment: Mac OSX Mountain Lion, Ruby 1.9.3, JRuby, RubyMine

Comment: I'd suggest you to install Ruby with [RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/)

Comment: I did install ruby with RVM....

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by an invalid usage of RVM. [Here's a similar issue](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/137).

The documentation for the gemsets is available at https://rvm.io/gemsets/.

Check the content of the `.rvmrc` file (or `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset` files) and make sure the required ruby version and gemset are available on your machine.

Comment: Hmmm...I'll take a look and report back.

Comment: Apparently this message is caused by having 2 config files (linux and osx).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this message is caused by having 2 config files (linux and osx).